# Qt Json decimal value

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt4, qt5

I have a JsonArray with an entry like: [1502054710762,-93.787]
I am using the [QDecimal](https://github.com/semihc/qdecimal) class in my project to work with real decimal values instead of float or double.
Now my problem is, that the value in the JsonArray is not a string. It is a JsonNumber as decimal. If I try to read the value throuh array.at(1).toDouble(), I generate an inaccurate decimal value.

Interesting point: this only happens on my Linux server, but runs fine on my Notebook. - No idea why...

Comment: I would suggest you to try _QJsonValue::toVariant()_ and then extract your value from the _QVariant_ using _QVariant::value()_. Basically, something like this: `QDecimal dec = array.at(1).toVariant().value<QDecimal>()`;.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use toDouble() to get it out as that changes the precision available. You're going to have to do your math with QDecimal.

Comment: Yeah right, but how to get the value out of the JSON array without the double thing?

Comment: you'll have to access it as a string.

Comment: But the format is no a string. It is a JsonNumber. I tried to read it like:
    `QDecDouble a;
    a.fromString( jsonArray.at(1).toString().toUtf8() );`

Comment: what's the value of array.at(1).toString()  ??

Comment: The string is empty, since the QJsonValue is **not** a string.
If I try to pick the value with `QJsonValue val = jsonArray.at(1);`, I can see in the debugger, that the value contains -93.787000000000006

Comment: Why not just use that then?

Comment: also... have you thought of parsing the json using a parsing library? https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp

Comment: I need the exact price for buy/sell stuff. Double is not an option.
I will check jsoncpp! Thank you.